# Xamarin: How to get HTML from page in WebView?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, web-scraping

Xamarin: How to get HTML from page in WebView?

I develop Xamarin App for iOS and I am using WebView.

Just to get HTML of page, I use the following code.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
using (Stream st = wc.OpenRead("http://study-csharp.blogspot.jp/")){
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st, Encoding.UTF8)){
        string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(html);
    }
}
```

However, I want HTML data after the user has logged in to the site in the webview.

I can't find the method to get HTML in UIWebView.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have editted my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use javascript `webView.EvaluateJavascript ("document.body.innerHTML")`

Comment: is tihs working for Xamarin Fomrs..

Comment: @SANDEEP see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859287/how-to-get-inner-html-source-from-webview-in-xamarin-form-c-sharp

Comment: and how to get HTML string in C# code?

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore in Xamarin Forms 4.6+