# How to load HTML page with javascript content in a WebView Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, javascript-injection

I am new in xamarin and c# forms platform. I make a simple webview application. and my main page is

```
namespace jsinjection
{
    public class WebviewPage : ContentPage
    {

        public WebviewPage ()
        {
            Content = new WebView {

                Source = "https://www.google.com.tr/",
                HeightRequest = 1000,
                WidthRequest = 1000
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do javascript injection to that webview according to platform specific data. But I dont know how to get this webview outside of its class. And which part of the project should I do injection.

Answer (score 2):

See if you can use the below code:

```
WebView wv = new WebView();
wv.EvaluateJavascript ("document.body.innerHTML");
```

or

```
wv.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.body.innerHTML" });
```

See also:
[Xamarin: How to get HTML from page in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825998/xamarin-how-to-get-html-from-page-in-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [`Xamarin.Forms.HtmlWebViewSource`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.HtmlWebViewSource/)

And here is an example:

```
// Get html content of your page.. 
// It could contain javascript code or references to files in the assets (example bellow).
string htmlText = MyItem.Article.ToString();

var browser = new WebView ();
var html = new HtmlWebViewSource {
  Html = htmlText
};

// Set your HTML content to implemented WebView
browser.Source = html;
```

Or using [`Xamarin.Forms.UrlWebViewSource`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.UrlWebViewSource/)

```
// Just use local URL for your HTML file that stores inside your application content.
browser.Source = new UrlWebViewSource {Url = "Content/index.html"};
```