# read return URL response after post back in xamarin froms webview

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I have implement Billdesk Payment gateway in Webview using Xamarin forms.and its working fine and open the payment gateway for payment but after the payment its returning a webpage with response success or fail which is also from Billdesk server.i want to read this response from  this return url page in my xamarin forms webview.can any one reply me for this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing html response content in Xamarin browser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747262/accessing-html-response-content-in-xamarin-browser-control)

Comment: yes but i don't want to go for native implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly bind the html to a HtmlWebViewSource in VM and check if html field is changed, or even further set the html field to another field in VM so you could get access to it. Then in setter, check for response you need.