# How to get inner html source from WebView in Xamarin Form - C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using WebView to load my authentication web page. After the successful authentication, I need to get some values from html source content. can anyone helm to read the source html from WebView?.

```
var webView= new WebView {
  Source = "https://www.MyLoginSite.com"
};
```

I have checked this thread : [Xamarin: How to get HTML from page in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825998/xamarin-how-to-get-html-from-page-in-webview)

I have written the below code after seeing above thread.

```
webView.Eval("document.body.innerHTML")
```

But the Eval is the void function, so how can I read value in C# code-behind or  is there any easy alternative method to get entire html content as string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing html response content in Xamarin browser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747262/accessing-html-response-content-in-xamarin-browser-control)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use HybridWebView from Xamarin-Forms-Labs and register a callback. Documentation is [here](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HybridWebView).

In your C# code register a callback:

```
this.hybridWebView.RegisterCallback("dataCallback", t => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(t));
```

Then evaluate some JS code calling the callback

```
this.hybridWebView.Eval("Native(\"dataCallback\", document.body.innerHTML);");
```

Comment: Hi artur, is there any easy alternative method to get entire html content as string?

Comment: @kombsh I don't think there is any.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```
 private async Task<string> GetHtml()
        {
            return await LoginWebViewItem.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.body.innerHTML");
        }
```

Then I call this from my method:

```
string AllHtml = await GetHtml();
```